# SQLServer em repositórios

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho que enviar um projeto de uma aplicação por um repositório GitHub, consegui fazer a aplicação funcionar perfeitamente front-End, Back-End e o banco de dados LOCAL, minha duvida é:

Tem como exportar o SQLServer para um repositório? Ou terei que colocar ele em algum servidor para a aplicação só ser baixada e executada?

Comment: Você quer enviar o banco? Por que não enviar as suas estruturas (tabelas e _views_) e programação (gatilhos, funções e procedimentos)? Ou você quer enviar dados também? O melhor dos mundos é você, para esse tipo de distribuição e manutenção, ter os scripts sql de criação dos objetos e de inserção dos dados no projeto

Comment: Gostaria que quem baixe-se minha aplicação só executasse a solução e pronto, no momento se eu executá-la em outro computador ela roda mas sem fazer os GET, POST, etc no SQLServer.

Comment: E acabei não respondendo a pergunta... Gostaria que já fosse uns dados sim, mas não é algo tão fundamental. Vou dar uma pesquisada sobre scripts SQL, se você tiver alguma documentação ficarei agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem várias formas, depende da forma como você está trabalhando.
Quando trabalha-se com Code First + Migrations seu banco de dados vai ser criado automaticamente, o migrations gera os scripts e controla as versões do banco de dados.
Acredito que você não esteja usando os recursos citados acima, mas fica a dica pros próximos projetos :)

Pro seu projeto atual, a melhor forma é gerar os scripts e fazer esse controle de criação manualmente.
Pra gerar os scripts no SQL Server Management Studio clique com o botão direito no banco de dados > Tarefas > Gerar Scripts, selecione todas as tabelas e o local pra exportação.

Após isso, coloca esse script numa classe do seu projeto e quando iniciar sua conexão com o banco faça uma verificação ou um tratamento de exceção pra validar se o banco não existe (cada modelo de connectionstring pede uma abordagem diferente, se tiver o nome do banco na sua connectionstring vai ter que tratar a exceção), então se não existir o banco de dados, roda o script de criação do banco de dados.
Crie também uma classe com os scripts de inserção pra rodar logo após a criação do banco de dados.

Comment: Sobre colocar o script em classes, eu não sou favorável. Prefiro deixar em um _asset_ separado, mas creio que isso dependa do gosto de cada um.